# Escape sequences appearing in socket messages

Tags: python, c, sockets

I'm working with two files, a generator (written in Python) which generates data , and a C-based socket server, which should listen and then process the data that the generator sends to it.

The generator creates batches of messages, where each message is separated by a \n. So an example batch would be: 
`x0x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987 \nx1x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987 \n`
In my C socket, I read 1000 bytes into a buffer. I want to split the total message into separate strings, separated by delimiter `\n`. I have done this, but I'm running into problems when the message exceeds the 1000 bytes length I mentioned before. If a message is not complete, i.e. it doesn't end in `\n`, I want to store whatever part of the message I did receive, and then use this to reconstruct the full message when the next 1000 bytes arrives.

What happens now when the batch length exceeds the buffer's 1000 bytes length is that some random character seems to be introduced. An example output (copied from the terminal) is shown below:

```
x0x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987 
x1x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x2x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x3x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x4x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x5x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x6x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x7x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x8x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x9x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x10x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x11x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x12x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x13x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x14x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x15x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x16x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x17x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x18x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x19x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x20x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x21x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x22x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x23x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x24x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x25x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x26x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x27x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x28x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x29x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x30x foo.bar.baz 45 1429694987
x31x foo.bar.baz 4▒▒▒p▒
```

My suspicion was that this problem was being caused by some of the characters being cut off somehow in transmission, but I haven't been able to figure out what is going wrong. I am not a C expert at all, and I'm struggling to find the problem. I've included my C code below: (apologies for any n00b mistakes!)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include "../librdkafka/src/rdkafka.h"

static const int PORT = 3135;

 //delta between these two allows for prefixing of cut off data.
static const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
static const int FULL_MSG_SIZE = 1200;
static const char *BROKERS = "192.168.50.11:9092";
static const char *TOPIC = "test";

/**
 * Socket error handling
 */
void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

/**
 * Kafka logger calback
 */
static void logger (const rd_kafka_t *rk, int level,
                    const char *fac, const char *buf) {
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "%u.%03u RDKAFKA-%i-%s: %s: %s\n",
                (int)tv.tv_sec, (int)(tv.tv_usec / 1000),
                level, fac, rd_kafka_name(rk), buf);
}

/**
 * Creates thread for each incoming connection and pushes data to Kafka.
 */
void *streamHandler(void *pnewsock){
    int number = * (int *) pnewsock;
    printf("Starting thread %d\n", number);
    /* Configuration */
    rd_kafka_topic_t *rkt;
    rd_kafka_t *rk;
    rd_kafka_conf_t *conf;
    rd_kafka_topic_conf_t *topic_conf;
    int partition = RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA;
    int quiet = 0;
    char errstr[512];

    /* Socket config */
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    int msg;

/* initialize kafka conf variables */
conf = rd_kafka_conf_new();
topic_conf = rd_kafka_topic_conf_new();

/* Create Kafka handle */
if (!(rk = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, conf,
                        errstr, sizeof(errstr)))) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "%% Failed to create new producer: %s\n",
                errstr);
        exit(1);
}

/* Set logger */
rd_kafka_set_logger(rk, logger);
rd_kafka_set_log_level(rk, LOG_DEBUG);

/* Add brokers */
if (rd_kafka_brokers_add(rk, BROKERS) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%% No valid brokers specified\n");
        exit(1);
}

/* Create topic */
rkt = rd_kafka_topic_new(rk, TOPIC, topic_conf);

strcpy(buffer, "");
char *last_msg = "";
char full_msg[FULL_MSG_SIZE] ;
bzero(full_msg, FULL_MSG_SIZE);
char * pch;
char delimiter[2] = "\n";
char *final;
int last_msg_complete = 0;
int res = 0;
while(1){
    if (recv(number, buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT) == 0){
        // connection has closed, so kill thread
        break;
    }

    msg = read(number, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE-1);
    if(msg < 0){
            error("ERROR reading from socket");
            break;
    }
    // prefix the last message (empty if no partial message from previous   transmit)
    printf("Concatenating now %s || %s", last_msg, buffer);
    strcat(full_msg, last_msg);
    strcat(full_msg, buffer);
    final = &full_msg[(strlen(full_msg)-1)];

    last_msg_complete = strcmp(delimiter, final); // 0 if ends in \n, other value otherwise

    // consume the received data and send to kafka.
    pch = strtok(full_msg, "\n");
    while(pch != NULL){            last_msg = '\0';
        last_msg = strdup(pch);

        pch = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        if ((pch != NULL) || (last_msg_complete == 0)){
                // only send this message if it isn't the last one
                // OR if it is the last one, only if it ends in \n
                res = rd_kafka_produce(rkt, partition,
                                RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY,
                                last_msg, strlen(last_msg),
                                NULL, 0,
                                NULL);
                if (res == -1){
                        fprintf(stderr,
                         "%% Failed to produce to topic %s "
                        "partition %i:%s \n",
                        rd_kafka_topic_name(rkt), partition,
                        rd_kafka_err2str(rd_kafka_errno2err(errno)));
                }
                if (!quiet){
                    printf("full_msg %s\n", full_msg);
                    printf("buffer %s\n", buffer);
                    printf("last_msg %s\n", last_msg);
                }
                rd_kafka_poll(rk, 0);
                free(last_msg);
        }
    }
    free(pch);
    // empty the buffer and full_msg.
    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    bzero(full_msg, FULL_MSG_SIZE);
}
printf("Killed thread connection %d\n", number);

/* Destroy topic */
rd_kafka_topic_destroy(rkt);

/* Destroy the handle */
rd_kafka_destroy(rk);
pthread_exit(&number);
return NULL;
}


int main(){
    int sock, newsock;
    pthread_t thread;
    int reuseaddr = 1;

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // create the listening socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1){
            perror("socket creation issue");
            return 1;
    }

    // enable the socket to reuse the address
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(int)) == -1){
            perror("socket address reuse");
            return 1;
    }

    // bind to address
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
            perror("bind error");
            return 1;
    }

    // Listen for new connections.
    listen(sock, 5);

    // When new connections arrive, create a thread with a socket object
    while(1){
            struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
            socklen_t size = sizeof(their_addr);
            puts("waiting");
            newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &size);
            puts("done waiting");

            if(newsock == -1){
                    perror("main loop accept error");
            } else{
                    printf("Connected to %s on port %d\n", inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr), their_addr.sin_port);
                    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, streamHandler, &newsock) != 0){
                            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create thread \n");
                    }
            }
    }

    close(sock);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: You need to use the return of `read` not just check it for errors. I also don't think using `strcat` with the buffer is a good idea as `read` does not introduce any `\0`. You could use `strncat` and give it `msg` which is the number of bytes `read` actually read

Comment: Ok, so how should I use the return value of `read`? Fair point about the lack of `\0` I think, but the output I show is the contents of buffer, so it isn't causing the weird characters I guess.

Comment: @danielvdende: Actually it probably is the cause of the weird characters. `strcat` will continue reading bytes until it gets to a `\0`. Since you haven't got one at the end of the buffer, you'll get the contents of the buffer plus whatever's after the buffer until there happens to be a `\0` in memory... so you'll get weird characters at the end of the last part-message that fits into the buffer.

Comment: @danielvdende `read` returns the number of bytes it read, in other words the number of actual data bytes it updated in the buffer. You should not use all the buffer as if `read` did actually read 1000 bytes. For example if your message is `"foo\n"`? `read` could return anything from a negative to 4, not necessarily reading all of it in one call.

Comment: @psmears - I'm not so sure - I think the code `bzero()`'s the buffer, but the flow isn't clear. Would definitely be clearer to skip the `bzero()` calls and just do `buffer[msg]='\0';` to NUL-terminate the string after checking the return from `read()` for errors.. Also, last_msg leaks when `strtok()` returns NULL, and the `free(pch)` call seems to be a free of non-malloc'd memory. And what happens if the `read()` call returns zero?  Lots of problems in there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It does `bzero()` the buffer, but that doesn't help, because it then does a `recv()` on the *whole* buffer (not `BUFFER_SIZE-1` as for the `read()`), which will overwrite all the zeros from `bzero()`.

Comment: @Eregrith Thank you! You were right, and after my previous comment I suddenly saw what you meant. This particular problem seems to be solved.

Comment: @psmears - Yes, that could definitely cause problems when the buffer gets filled up.  There's no point to the `recv()` call.  It's useless as the connection can close when the process is blocked in the later `read()` call anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Actually the `read()` shouldn't ever block, because the `recv()` and check for `0` guarantees there is data in the buffer. I agree the `recv()` doesn't achieve anything though, because it can return `0` if the connection hasn't closed, but no data has been received yet...

Comment: @psmears - If `recv()` returns zero, `read()` will block until data is received - or the connection is closed.  On a connection with any real latency, closing down the connection will take some time, so it's a likely problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, because if `recv()` returns zero, the `break` means `read()` doesn't even get called :)

Comment: @psmears - So if there's no data in the buffer yet, the thread closes the connection?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's what the code appears to say. I'm not claiming it's a good idea :)

Comment: @ALL. Thank you all for your input! :) I really appreciate it. I have replaced the bzeros, as @AndrewHenle suggested; I have also fixed the issue with `read` returning 0. @psmears, now you mention it, it sounds like a bad idea; how should I fix this? From your discussion I understand that the `recv` check doesn't do much, but also doesn't do any harm. I've removed it for now, as it seems the `read() == 0` check I mentioned already catches a connection closed. Should I do more?

Comment: @psmears - It's too early to be doing this sans caffeine...  :)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Actually on second thoughts, in that case `recv` won't return `0`, it'll return `-1/EWOULDBLOCK`, so it will drop through to the `read()`, and so `read()` can indeed block. Sorry about that - you're right about the caffeine ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens when `read()` returns zero when the connection closes?  The `recv()` call with `MSG_PEEK` is **not** likely to tell you the connection is closed - you'll most likely fall down into the `read()`, block, and have the `read()` return zero when the connection closes.

In other words, doing a non-blocking `recv()` with `MSG_PEEK` to check for a closed connection doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, good point. I found this while searching online, but as I said, I'm no C expert. How should you check for a closed connection?

Comment: Check the return from `read()` for zero.  If it's zero, the connection closed.  `... else if ( 0 == msg ) { break; }` after the if statement checking `msg = read(...)` for an error.